# Delete mySql row with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, row, sql-delete

I have shop site and want to be able delete what I add but can't seem to get it to work.

All relevant code is below:

Home page:

```
<?php
  //external pages area
  include_once('config/database.php');
  include_once('object/chair.php');
  //grabs info from the various pages.sql files
  $database = new Database();
  $conn = $database->getConnection();
  $chair = new Chair($conn);
  //connection made with sql file
  $stmt = $chair->readAll();
  //reading all the data in the sql file
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
    <div class="ProductActionAdd" style="display:;">
      <a href="chair-details.php?detailsid=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" class="btn">Buy me!</a>
    </div>
```

Details page:

```
<?php
  include_once('config/database.php');
  include_once('object/chair.php');
  $database = new Database();
  $conn = $database->getConnection();
  $chair = new Chair($conn);
  $chair->id = $_GET['detailsid'];
  $stmt = $chair->readDetails();
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
    <a href='delete-chair.php?detailsid=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>' class="deleteit">deleate</a>
```

Delete page:

```
<?php
  include_once('config/database.php');
  include_once('object/chair.php');
  $database = new Database();
  $conn = $database->getConnection();
  $chair = new Chair($conn);
  $chair->id = $_GET['detailsid'];
  $stmt = $chair->readAll();
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
    <div class="center_items">
      <div class="all-items">
        <?php   
          $sql="DELETE FROM office_chairs WHERE id ='{$chair->id}'";    
  }
        ?>
```

It states that `detailsID` is undefined and that Object of class chairs can't be converted into a string.

Answer (score 1):

Well... you're receiving the `detailsid` parameter through `$_GET` and then you appoint it to a property called `id`.

```
$chair->id = $_GET['detailsid'];
```

Thus, calling a variable with the name $detailsid is not possible - cause no such variable exist. Use the property you assigned the value too instead.

The $chair variable contains a new instance of the class Chair. I don't know what your intentions are? Is the database table name dynamic? If not, just write the table name.

Correcting your query from

```
$sql="DELETE FROM $chair WHERE id = '$chair->id'";
```

to:

```
$sql="DELETE FROM table_name_here WHERE id ='$detailsid'";
```

might fix your problem giving the result you wish for. But your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should consider using prepared statments instead of directly connecting the variables to your query.

For example

```
$sql="DELETE FROM table_name_here WHERE id = ?";
$stmt -> $con = prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute(array($chair -> id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Update

`$sql="DELETE FROM $chair WHERE id ='$detailsid'";`

to

`$sql="DELETE FROM chair WHERE id ='{$chair->id}'";`